# How to access memory information in Matlab on Unix - equivalent of user view.MaxPossibleArrayBytes

Tags: matlab, unix, memory

I am looking for an equivalent of the data returned by memory on windows platform on unix, in matlab.

I am aware of the possibility of using unix('vm_stat'), but the specific part of information I require is the largest contiguous free memory block.

This information is returned by memory as follows:

```
[userview, ~] = memory;
a = userview.MaxPossibleArrayBytes
```

Does anybody no how to write a unix command that could return this same information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call command 'free' and parse the results. This works on linux

```
[r,w] = unix('free | grep Mem');
stats = str2double(regexp(w, '[0-9]*', 'match'));
memsize = stats(1)/1e6;
freemem = (stats(3)+stats(end))/1e6;
```

The output is in Gbytes. The last number free returns is 'cached' memory used by the OS, e.g. dynamic libraries. It can in general be used, but you can decide to leave it out and just use what free reports as 'Free' - the third numerical field in the output.

**Edit** On Linux, memory allocation within MATLABs mxMalloc/mxCalloc most likely simply calls malloc and friends. To get a hint that this is the case do the following experiment. In a mex file allocate an array using the following code, and return it to MATLAB:

```
  rout = calloc(sizeof(Double),M*N);
  pargout[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(0,0,mxDOUBLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
  mxSetM(pargout[0], m);
  mxSetN(pargout[0], n);
  mxSetData(pargout[0], rout);
  mexMakeMemoryPersistent(rout);
```

You can normally use the variable returned in MATLAB. You can even clear it - this does not cause any problems. If indeed MATLAB simply uses malloc, there is no way that I know of in which they can enforce physically contiguous memory.

I know that you can not run the above code on Windows though. This code crashes MATLAB. Of course, you should not do that in your codes. It merely illustrates the point.

Comment: Thanks - a couple of problems though - first one is that free is not available on osx. There are other ways to get that info though. BUT - it looks like you are matching the total memory available, and what I'm after is the largest contiguous block available?

Comment: I do not think that from the users perspective physically contiguous blocks of memory have any meaning on OSX. I know that MATLAB claims they use contiguous memory to store arrays, but with a virtual memory OS the allocated memory is always 'virtually' contiguous. Physical contiguous memory is needed only in special cases (kernel code, device mapped memory). I don't really think MATLAB has any way to enforce physically contiguous allocation. Moreover, I am almost sure they simply use malloc and friends. Look at the edited comment for a code showing why I think so.

Comment: I looked around and found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25725-largest-memory-block-available-all-platforms). The guy repeatedly tries to allocate memory, reducing the size of the array if he fails. I would strongly discourage you to do such things :) Depends on configuration, but you may end up swaping quite a lot instead of getting an OOM..

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your time - I am sold now! My code involves reading a very large file, so I will work just on the mem free and not worry about contiguous allocation on this platform. It seems to be working anyway. BW Steven (PS I will vote up your answer once I get to 15 reputation)

Comment: This answer doesn't give correct results on linux