# Matlab: use of memory

Tags: matlab, unix, memory, memory-management

I have several "out of memory" problems using MATLAB. I don't understand exactly if Matlab can use (or not) all the ram memory of my computer. This is the problem: my computer has 4gb of ram memory and 2 gb for Swap memory (my OS is Linux/Ubuntu 12.10), but Matlab only uses up to 2.6 gb and then shows the warning: "out of memory".

Is it possible to fix this and allow Matlab to use all the "available" memory?

Thanks.

Comment: Your OS and other applications use some memory. How do you know that the available memory is more than 2.6 GB? Anyway, typing `memory` on Matlab commnand window may give you more information

Comment: using the system monitor (in ubuntu) I obtain all the information I want. The available memory of the system is 3.9gb, and also when I'm working with Matlab I can check the memory use by the other programms and that's not the problem, I mean Matlab only use up to 2.6 gb, and it has more memory available. The command "memory" only works on Windows matlab version, in ubuntu I've tried with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350598/how-to-access-memory-information-in-matlab-on-unix-equivalent-of-user-view-max]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're running 32bit linux and or 32bit MATLAB.

If you allow for enough swap, a process can take up to its virtual memory address space worth of memory.

Generally for 32bit linux you're limited to 3gb of address space for any process (the last gb is kernel memory space).  It's entirely possible, depending on usage patterns, that at 2.6gb the next request for memory can't complete because there isn't enough /contiguous/ memory to satisfy it.  This is especially common when growing large arrays.

Upgrading to a 64bit version of linux/windows/macOS with 64bit MATLAB should solve this problem but even so, using 3gb+ of virtual address space on a system with 4gb of ram is probably going to start making things very slow.

Comment: Yes, like you said: I solved the problem in some sense, in this link [http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html], there's an explanation of the memory limits of matlab, it shows a list of MATLAB supported operating systems and their process limits. In conclution it's true that there is a limit for the available memory of matlab, and it depends on the number of bits of the OS and the respectly number of the matlab version. Obviously that limit is going to be less than the total available memory of the computer. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Some googling brought up [this](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7471821):

> MATLAB will use as much memory as your OS lets it use;
> the only way to increase the amount of memory MATLAB can use is to reduce
> the amount of memory occupied by other applications or to give the OS more
> memory to partition out to the applications.

So no, there's no easy way to tell matlab to use more memory.
You either have to buy more memory, optimize your code, run your scripts/functions with less output to store at once or reduce memory usage by other procedures that are running.
Here are some helpful links though:

[memory management functions](https://web.archive.org/web/20140608150735/http://www.mathworks.de:80/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-management-functions.html)

[memory allocation](https://web.archive.org/web/20140608151559/http://www.mathworks.de:80/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html)

[related discussion on the mathworks forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20151115015149/http://www.mathworks.com:80/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/308318)

Comment: I think there's some kind of limit of the available memory for Matlab, it's not seem to be true that Matlab can use as much memory as my system allows it. With only 500mb of memory used, I made a little programm in c++ to "sature" the memory and it worked, I could see how it "catched" the whole memory (4gb). And after that I tried to "sature" the memory only using matlab but again , I couldn't (it only used 2.6 gb....)

Comment: @Javier Gargiulo nevertheless, there's no function to tell matlab to use more memory from within matlab.