# How to Get Free Swap Memory for Matrix Computation in Linux Matlab?

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu, memory, swap

Situation: estimate if you can compute big matrix with your Ram and Swap in Linux Matlab
I need the sum of `Mem` and `Swap`, corresponding values by `free -m` under Heading *total* in Linux

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7925        3114        3646         308        1164        4220
Swap:         28610          32       28578
```

Free Ram memory in Matlab by

```
% http://stackoverflow.com/a/12350678/54964
[r,w] = unix('free | grep Mem');
stats = str2double(regexp(w, '[0-9]*', 'match'));
memsize = stats(1)/1e6;
freeRamMem = (stats(3)+stats(end))/1e6;
```

Free Swap memory in Matlab: ...

Relation between Memory requirement and Matrix size of Matlab: ...

### Testing Suever's 2nd iteration

Suever's command gives me 29.2 GB that is corresponding to `free`'s output so correct

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8115460     4445520     1956672      350692     1713268     3024604
Swap:      29297656       33028    29264628
```

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6
Linux kernel options: wl, zswap
Matlab: 2016a
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
Ram: 8 GB
Swap: 28 Gb on SSD (set up like in the thread [How to Allocate More Space to Swap and Increase its Size Greater than Ram?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297767/16920))
SSD: 128 GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make a slight modification to the code that you've posted to get the swap amount.

```
function freeMem = freeMemory(type)
    [r, w] = unix(['free | grep ', type]);
    stats = str2double(regexp(w, '[0-9]*', 'match'));
    memsize = stats(1)/1e6;

    if numel(stats) > 3
        freeMem = (stats(3)+stats(end))/1e6;
    else
        freeMem = stats(3)/1e6;
    end
end

totalFree = freeMemory('Mem') + freeMemory('Swap')
```

To figure out how much memory a matrix takes up, use the size of  the datatype and multiply by the number of elements as a first approximation.

Comment: @Masi Updated the answer

Comment: @Masi `-m` is the output in megabytes whereas `free` is in bytes

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "configuration". The dimensions do not matter. As far as estimating memory usage during calculations, you'll have to monitor it to determine that

Comment: @Masi Why would I use `@(...)` You asked how to get the swap memory, how to integrate that into your program to monitor usage over time is really beyond the scope of this question.